# Applying approxQuantile on a window in Scala (Spark dataframe)

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

As I understand, one can obtain quantiles with
    df.stat.approxQuantile

Is it possible to calculate quantiles on a window partitioned by a certain column?

Since, I am looking to obtain specific quantiles, the method percent_rank() - method that can be applied on a window - does not accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you know this *"certain column"* values you can do something like this:

```
for (value <- certainColumnValueList){
    val apQuantile = df.select($"certain_column" === value).stat.approxQuantile(...)
    // Do something with this result like appending it on a Map
    // as (value -> apQuantile) ...
}
```

If you want to use window, you must define your own function that computes this quantiles and define it as a [UDAF](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udaf-scala.html) (user defined aggregate function).

Hope this helps with your problem.